# HttpClient.PostAsXmlAsync With Specific DateTime Formatting

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, serialization, dotnet-httpclient

I am looking to send XML to a web service using the extension method `HttpClient.PostAsXmlAsync<T>` in the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` NuGet package (version 5.2.3). However, it formats dates in the format:

`yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss+hh:mm`

Whereas the web service states that the XML needs to be formatted in a specific format that does not have the colon (:) in the time zone, so: `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss+hhmm`.

Is there a way to override how the HttpClient formats dates when converting the object? I *could* make the dates strings on the object of type T, but I would prefer not to as the objects' code is actually generated from an XSD supplied.

Comment: Yes.  In the class to you should be able to add a Get/Set that converts a string to a DateTime using ParseExact.  The class specifies the xml as a string variable and then converts to a private DateTime.